# Featured image from external link

Tags: image, wordpress

Is there some way to let me insert external image to Wordoress at the section of "fuatured image" from external source? 
I like the image be visible at the home page but not at the post. the image at the home page need to link to the post.

Wordpress doesn't allow to insert image from external link as features image (only to post).
Couldn't find any proper solution till now in the net.

Help?
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

you can add external images to wordpress post. when you click on featured image it open a modal box there are three tab the 2nd tab lets you insert the external image i.e. you can put an external URL of media, then there is wordpress function to get featured image.

so you can it using.

```
get_post_thumbnail($post_id, $size, $attr);
```

post_id (integer) (Optional) Post ID.

Default: Post ID

size
(string/array) (Optional) Either a string keyword (thumbnail, medium, large or full) or a 2-item array representing width and height in pixels, e.g. array(32,32).

Default: 'post-thumbnail'

attr
    (string/array) (optional) Query string or array of attributes. See wp_get_attachment_image.
    Default: None

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_post_thumbnail

and for permalink you can use

```
the_permalink();
```

hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

I've posted this elsewhere, but how about this plugin?

http://epicplugins.com/external-url-link-to-featured-images/

It lets you add featured images from an external URL.

There's also a Chrome extension: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/post-to-wordpress/hhmhfcfbheceghfbfjgkjnlhooadpnej which does a really good job.